Optimize command-error-logging function (discord.py)
I want a system where, upon encountering an error in a slash command, a message is sent to the room describing the error (such as MissingPermission or UnknownInteraction), without the need for multiple checkers in each slash command, in order to save time and avoid receiving any print() statements. I am using 'tree' for slash commands. I have attempted various approaches, but the event does not trigger except with on_interaction. However, I'm unsure if we can retrieve the error value in this scenario.
Current function ('tree' with ugly if-statements)
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
      await ctx.send("Cette commande n'existe pas.")
  elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
      await ctx.send("Il manque un argument requis pour exécuter cette commande.")
  elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
      await ctx.send(f"Cette commande est en cooldown. Réessayez dans {round(error.retry_after, 1)} secondes.")
  elif isinstance(error, commands.NotOwner):
      await ctx.send("Vous n'avez pas la permission d'exécuter cette commande.")
  else:
      await ctx.send(f"Une erreur est survenue lors de l'exécution de la commande : {error}")


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
